# Найти гласные/согласные буквы в предложении

Tags: javascript

Пользователь вводит предложение. Нам нужно найти количеств гласных/согласных букв в предложении. Как это реализовать **БЕЗ** использования регулярных выражений?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Я бы рад, но у меня даже вариантов нет. В примере кода я разве что смогу написать функцию, которая присваивает переменной значение input, где вписывают предложение.

Comment: Ну тогда посмотрите ответ от @Grundy - он очень старался, отвечая вам.

Answer (score 7):

Сначала нужно завести два списка:

1. символы, которые будут считаться гласными
2. символы, которые будет считаться согласными

Для нахождения количества чего-то в строке, необходимо в цикле обойти всю строку. сделать это можно с помощью циклов [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) или [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

На каждой итерации цикла необходимо проверить, находится ли проверяемый символ в одном из списков, например с помощью [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

И если находится - увеличить соответствующий счетчик.

Comment: каков вопрос - таков и ответ (ответ в положительном смысле). :-)

Comment: Я думал об этом, но мне показалось что вписывать каждую гласную/согласную букву очень странный способ. Думал есть какой-нибудь метод или что-то в этом роде (я новичек).
Спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: @Juzo, Ну надо же как-то указать интерпретатору что считать "гласной" или какой ещё буквой.

Comment: Ну не списки, а множества все-таки.